# Examining precise style information of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran into a situation where it became desirable to be able to tell if a certain element has a bottom border, using Javascript.

I thought this would be as easy as using `getComputedStyle` on the element, and looking for "borderBottom" in the resulting style sheet object.

Well, it seems it's a bit more complicated if you care about cross-browser compatibility.  I'm not talking about supporting ancient things like IE 6, 7 or even 8 (which don't even have `getComputedStyle`) - I'm talking about supporting relatively *modern* browsers.

And it seems that different browsers do different things in this regard.

Let's take a very simple style sheet:

```
.foo,
.bar {
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.foo {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Suppose I want to get the computed "`border-bottom`" value here.  Even though no actual `border-bottom` property is set, it will be computed via the `border` property.

So, on Chrome version 37 (not the latest version but pretty "modern"), if I call `getComputedStyle` on some element that uses class `bar`, I get: `3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)` as expected.

However, on Firefox (version 28 - again not the latest version but still pretty "modern") I simply get an empty string for the `"borderBottom"` style.

So, I wrote a small script to iterate over the computed style sheet and see what Chrome and Firefox are actually producing:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("example"));
for (var key in style) console.log("STYLE: " + key + " " + style[key]);
```

Both browsers output a HUGE list of computed styles.  Sure enough, with Chrome I see:

```
STYLE: borderBottom 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

But Mozilla doesn't provide anything like that.  It provides a mix of style rules, along with native code internal functions like:

```
"STYLE: item function item() {
    [native code]
}"
```

I dumped the output for both browsers on a public jsfiddle (not meant to be executed, it's just plaintext output I dumped there):

**[The output for Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/ejkqk9Lk/3/)**

**[The output for Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/8e3j9tt8/2/)**

As you can see, they're pretty different.

[**And here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8oxme9th/2/) showing the actual code I used to generate these lists:

(Note that the output is displayed in the browser's console, in most browsers press the <kbd>F12</kbd> button to view the developer console.)

So, is there some known cross-browser strategy for doing this?  How can I find the computed style for a particular property (like `borderBottom`) in a way that works on all modern browsers?  Is this something that's even W3C standardized?

Or is this something that's pretty much too convoluted to attempt to do without a library?

Comment: it would be easier to check if an element has a class that gives a bottom border.

Comment: you will need to write a parser to handle different browser return formats. It gets even more complex with other CSS3 properties mixed in sometimes

Comment: Could you post the runnable code that produces the output that you pasted, that way we can run the demos ourselves and see if there's any non-obvious errors in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the problem is that `border` is a shorthand property of `border-width`, `border-style`, `border-color`. And `border-width` is a shorthand of `border-*-width`, etc.

Then, setting `border` sets `border-bottom-*` properties, but not `border-bottom`. Therefore, you get the empty string on Firefox.

However, the following will work:

```
getComputedStyle(element).borderBottomWidth
```